# Java: send an execution to a certain thread

Tags: java, multithreading, completable-future

I'm playing around with threads and I'm wondering if it's possible to force a thread to execute something.

So, the thing is I have some method like this:

```
public void asyncSleep() {
    Supplier<Boolean> sleeper = () -> {

        try {
            Thread.sleep(4000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }

        return true;
    };

    CompletableFuture<Boolean> promise = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(sleeper, ex);
    promise.thenAccept(u -> {
        System.out.println("thread=" + Thread.currentThread());
    });
}
```

And I'd need the original thread (the one executing the `asyncSleep()` method) to be the one executing the `thenAccept`. Is that even possible? And if so, how can I do it?

Comment: Can you please explain why you want to do that? Also, must `asyncSleep()` return before the execution of `thenAccept()`?

Comment: I have a kafka streams application that needs to perform a thread blocking operation (such as a long HTTP request). That causes the kafka thread to be blocked for a long time, so it's not managing as much kafka messages as it should. I'm trying to unblock that thread using the CompletableFuture, but in the ```thenAccept()``` I need to go back to the original kafka stream context. I've tried implementing that, but the method to forward the execution that usually works in kafka is not working in this case, and I assumed it had something to do with the thread.That's why I was trying this approach

Comment: @gualizoe I think you should ask a question about your real Kafka issue instead, this is the typical [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/167668)

Comment: The idea of making an arbitrary thread stopping whatever it’s currently doing to perform another job, is already quite ambitious. But think it to the end; what if that particular thread finished in the meanwhile and is not even running anymore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it to be working in the non blocking way and you still want that original thread (the one that executes `asyncSleep`) to also execut method that you pass into `thenAccept` then the only way is as follows:

You'd need to use an `ExecutorService` with just single thread. Execute `asyncSleep` with this executor, but then, you'll have to pass the same executor into `thenAcceptAsync` (instead of `thenAccept`) as a second argument.

Then if your thread didn't crash and wasn't replaced by the executor with new  thread, it should be exactly the same thread executing both methods.

But that's an artificial use case.

Comment: I like your answer, but it's not possible for my use case because the original thread is a kafka-streams managed thread (and that's why I need to send the execution again to that same thread after the promise is finished). Thanks anyway!

Comment: I assume you want to commit offset when you know that everything was truly finished and only then proceed to next message that this consumer pulled. If that's the case then just implement entire message handler in a synchronous way. If you call some API that works truly asynchronously (i.e. returns CompletableFuture) just do a blocking get on it.

Comment: No, I want just the opposite: I want to process as many messages as I can while a time-consuming operation is executed in the background, so I can't block the kafka thread. But in the moment that time-consuming operation finishes, I need to go back to process the message, and for that I need to go back to the kafka stream thread. So to sum up: I need kafka thread to execute the whole life of the message except the time-consuming part, that can be executed by another thread pool.

Comment: Marked as accepted because it didn't solve my original problem but I believe it's a valid answer.